# Time session of admin account in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My website is based on ASP NET Core. There is admin account. But session of this account lasts 6 minutes and then the website requires a login again. How can I increase time of session? There is no code about the session, maybe it is default value. 
login page:

```
https://pasteb in.com/vxhqxy3a
```

Comment: it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @Dortimer thats for classic asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your session state options in the ConfigureServices method of your startup class. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-session-state but I don't see any way of changing the timeout by user role.

The default session timeout is 20 minutes so there must be something else setting the 6 minute timeout you are experiencing.